# Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be measurable. Assume that $0 \le f \le 1$ and that $f(x)=0$, when $x \notin [0,1]^n$. Show that $\int f \le 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be measurable. Assume that $0 \le f \le 1$ and that $f(x)=0$, when $x \notin [0,1]^n$. Show that $\int f \le 1$.

I have that $$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f = \int_{0}^1 f + \int_{1}^\infty f.$$

Now when $x > 1$ $f(x) = 0$ so $\int_{1}^\infty f  = 0$ and so $$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f = \int_{0}^1 f \le \int_{0}^1 1 = \chi_{[0,1]} \le 1.$$

Is this correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is correct, but the notation needs fixing. Since the integral is over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}$, you can't write real limits for the integral in the way you have done. Write instead
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}f  = \int_{[0,1]^n}f + \int_{\mathbb{R^n}\setminus[0,1]^n}f= \int_{[0,1]^n}f \le \int_{[0,1]^n} 1 = 1
$$